# Cardview is all goes into one card

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-cards

I have made and app with CardView, but my cardview is going into one card.

My Code:

recyclerview_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

[I get something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULCn1.png)

Comment: Please copy your item.xml here and also the screenshot of what you are getting with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue is with the gap between your `CardViews`. You must not be having `CompatPadding` true in `CardView` thats why it looks like the data is clubbed into one `CardView` try making it true.
Use following code it should work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/person_age"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by returning action bar! Your question had no action bar point. What exactly is the issue with the action bar. I answered your question for cardview issue and I guess that is working now. Right?

Comment: You can take help from here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html  .  If my answer is correct for your cardview problem then mark it as answer. Thanks